# Drag the view controller instead of swipe gesture

Tags: ios, swift

I want to go back to the previous ViewController by swiping from the left edge of the screen. I got this code to do this

```
let swipeRecognizer = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissViewController))
swipeRecognizer.edges = .left
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRecognizer)
```

but I don't want to go back to every single gesture it recognizes, I want it to work just like the other apps where you can drag the view controller back and forth, instead of doing a little swipe and the app just going back to the previous ViewController. What code should I use?

Answer (score 0):

A swipe gesture is a "one shot" gesture. It's not a continuous gesture. Thus it's the wrong choice. If you want to be able to drag your view controller so that it "peeks" onto the screen and gradually drags over, you need to use a pan gesture recognizer and move your view as the user does the pan gesture.

However, implementing that is a fair amount of work. You might want to look at using a UIPageViewController. That is a "container" view controller that manages 2 or more child view controllers and handles the transition between them for you. You can set it up to either use a page curl transition like iBooks, or a slide transition, which is what you want.

Comment: Well I feel like there is no need to reinvent the wheel, I found a cocoapod that does exactly what I want. https://cocoapods.org/pods/PullToDismiss

Comment: Ok, cool. You should post that as an answer to your question and then accept it, so others with the same question can learn from what you found.